# Callback on Bean save?

Tags: blocks

Is there any callback hook like hook_node_insert / hook_node_update when saving a bean block?

Comment: hook_entity_insert/update?

Answer (score 0):

Beans use the entity system, so you have a couple options here:

As AyeshK stated, [hook_entity_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_entity_insert) and [hook_entity_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_entity_update) are the obvious options.

If you need to do something before creating OR updating you can use [hook_entity_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_entity_presave).

Finally, Drupal doesn't have any native hooks that runs *after* an entity is created/updated, but the [Hook Post Action module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action) offers a nice set of additional functions to solve this problem.  If you don't want yet another module dependency, read the module's codebase and figure out how it implements the post-save functionality, then add similar custom code in your own module.